# Swift 3 upload image to Parse Server

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I'm trying to upload an image to Parse Server usinf **PFFile**. I'm not having issues uploading it manually from **Parse Dashboard** and retrieving it from the app. But if I try to upload a new one with this method, the image is not being updated.

The rest of fields are beeing uploaded correctly *(name, lastname, username and email)*

**Save method:**

```
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Start saving...")

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image!)
    print ("imageData value:")
    print(imageData!)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.png", data:imageData!)
    print ("imageFile value:")
    print(imageFile!)

    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
    if let user = objects {
        for object in user {
            object["name"] = self.nameFld.text
            object["lastname"] = self.lastnameFld.text
            object["username"] = self.emailFld.text
            object["email"] = self.emailFld.text
            object["avatar"] = imageFile

            print(object)
            object.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
    })

}
```

**Output**:

```
Start saving...
imageData value:
8358983 bytes
(lldb)
```

Comment: If you just want save image for the `currentUser` only I don't see any point of first querying the user and then updating the image. You may simply upload the image aka `PFFile` and save it as the avatar of `currentUser`. As far as I know the `imageFile` isn't accessible in the `findObjectsInBackground` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this work you will need to upload picture only first and then reference it to the user

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image!)
print ("imageData value:")
print(imageData!)
let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.png", data:imageData!)
print ("imageFile value:")
print(imageFile!)

imageFile.saveInBackground { (result, error) in
    if let error = error{
        print(error)
    }else{
        let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo (PFUser.current()?.username)!)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if let user = objects {
                for object in user {
                    object["name"] = self.nameFld.text
                    object["lastname"] = self.lastnameFld.text
                    object["username"] = self.emailFld.text
                    object["email"] = self.emailFld.text
                    object["avatar"] = imageFile

                    print(object)
                    object.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
}
```

Be aware that in the above example the file is always uploaded to the server even if no users match the query so consider uploading file only after getting query results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it shoes this output:

8406442 bytes
<PFFile: 0x60800024d440>
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: @DaniPolo Can you try changing file initialization to `let imageFile =  PFFile(data: data:imageData!, contentType: "image/png")`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to query current user. You can do it as follows:

```
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let userToUpdate = PFUser.current()!

    userToUpdate["name"] = self.nameFld.text
    userToUpdate["email"] = self.emailFld.text
    userToUpdate["username"] = self.emailFld.text

    // Save Avatar
    if profilePic.image != nil {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic.image!, 0.5)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.jpg", data:imageData!)
        userToUpdate["avatar"] = imageFile
    }

    // Saving block
    userToUpdate.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Your Profile has been updated!")
       } else {
            print("Failed")

    }})
}
```